# Google chart custom drawing (arrows, text near arrows, colored text labels and parabola curves)

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I need to display my data something like this (using Google chart):

[image]

Horizontal bar is definitely a **BarChart** but I have no idea howto perform custom drawing (arrows, text near arrows and colored text labels).

More complex chart that I need looks like:
[image]

I've tried to use **ComboChart** with stacked **BarCharts** and curved **LineChart** using following:

```
var options = {
                'width': 600,
                'height': 500,
                isStacked: true,
                seriesType: 'bars',
                series: { 3: { type: 'line', curveType: 'function' } },
                orientation: 'vertical'
            };
```

but on resulting image parabola curve (**LineChart** with three points) looks ugly:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it will be difficult, nearly impossible using standard chart options. the chart is drawn using SVG, and you can add your own SVG elements, on the chart's `'ready'` event. check [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61638350/5090771) -- custom circles ("points") are added to a bar chart. it will give you an idea of what it will take, the chart methods you can use to place elements, etc... -- you could add triangles for the arrows -- and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61591276/5090771) might offer another tip as well...

Comment: @WhiteHat [First answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61627353/how-to-insert-points-on-top-of-bar-charts-using-google-charts/61638350#61638350) is very usefull for drawing svg elements, thank you. But [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61587979/vertical-line-annotation-in-horizontal-bar-using-google-chart/61591276#61591276) is not exact what I'm looking for: `annotation` and `annotationText` are limited to their positions. But I what to draw a colored text labels at arbitary locations (as you can see on my picture).